# Get installed applications page link in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I replaced my new tab page with an extension. Some extensions put a link into the standard new tab page (into applications tab).

Now I can't see those links. 
Is there a shortcut to the applications page? I know I can copy the application link but I don't want to do that every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on the dev channel, you should be able to access it by [entering `chrome://apps` in the omnibox](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/url_constants.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=23).

If this gives an invalid URL, you can use Chrome's Internal URL scheme for New Tab page `chrome-internal://newtab/` to bring up the built-in new-tab page & then click on the apps.

Note that by default `chrome-internal://newtab/` will do a Google search, so select the second option to visit the page rather than do the search

Comment: Thanks, I used chrome-internal://newtab/ as a bookmark. Note: you can not add chrome-internal://newtab/ as a link in an extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could try enabling the chrome app launcher by going to `chrome://flags` and enabling "Show Chrome App Launcher"

[image]

This would allow you to access your apps from the taskbar which is a lot easier than having to navigate to the new tab, going to apps and then clicking on your prefered app:

[image]